# Form.Request event does not fire

Tags: javascript, mootools, mootools-more

I'm having trouble with events in a MooTools `Form.Request()`:

```
new Form.Request(e.getParent('form'), $('update'), {
    resetForm: false,
    onRequest: function () {
        loading(e)
    },
    onSuccess: function () {
        toggle(e)
    }
}).send();
```

The `onSuccess` event triggers happy, but the `onRequest` event does nothing. Am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the event is `send` not `request`. So you are looking for `onSend:`.

Have a closer look at the **[documentation](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Forms/Form.Request)**:

> #### Events:
>
> - **send** - *(function)* The function to execute when the request is sent. Passed the form being submitted and the data (an object) being submitted.
> - **failure** - *(function)* The function to execute when the request fails. Passed the XHR that is returned by Request on failure.
> - **success** - *(function)* The function to execute when the request succeeds. Passed the target being updated, the request text, and the request xml.